# Referencing individual pins, in Hex, Bit masking

Tags: hex

I'm using a netduino plus 2, and need to understand how to convert an individual pins's number into hex for bit masking, eg:

PERSUDO

```
if counter_value_bit_1 is 1, do:
    write 1 to D0 pin
else
    write 0 to D0 pin

..... counting from bit_1 through bit_9.
if counter_value_bit_9 is 1, do:
    write 1 to D0 pin
else
    write 0 to D0 pin
```

Answer

```
if (counter_value & 0x01) {        //bit_1
    ...}
if (counter_value & 0x200) {       //bit_9
    ...}
```

My question: how do you get 0x200 = bit 9, ect?
An example or two for bits in between 1 and 9 would be great.

THANKS

Answer (score 0):

Which language do you use?
In C you cant handle a bit "9" in a portable way, see byte ordering. If you know the byte order you could extract the byte with bit 9.

```
#define BYTE_WITH_BIT_9 ...
int counter_value = 42;
((char*)counter_value)[BYTE_WITH_BIT_9]
```

Cast to `char*` to access the raw bytes. Then chose the byte and now you can do magic bit operations.